# Trying to imitate a drawing

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I am very new to Tex Exchange. I hope you guys can help me out with this drawing:

[image]

MWE [Source code](https://texample.net/media/tikz/examples/TEX/porter-model.tex):

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article} 

\usepackage[hmargin=2cm,vmargin=1cm]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{bch} % change default font

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,fit,positioning,shapes.symbols,chains}

%%%<
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[active,tightpage,floats]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}%
%%%>

\begin{comment}
:Title: Porter model

A Porter five (or six) forces model.


\end{comment}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% BEGIN DOCUMENT
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]

\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
[node distance = 1cm, auto,font=\footnotesize,
% STYLES
every node/.style={node distance=3cm},
% The comment style is used to describe the characteristics of each force
comment/.style={rectangle, inner sep= 5pt, text width=4cm, node distance=0.25cm, font=\scriptsize\sffamily},
% The force style is used to draw the forces' name
force/.style={rectangle, draw, fill=black!10, inner sep=5pt, text width=4cm, text badly centered, minimum height=1.2cm, font=\bfseries\footnotesize\sffamily}] 

% Draw forces
\node [force] (rivalry) {Rivalry among existing competitors};
\node [force, above of=rivalry] (substitutes) {Threat of substitutes};
\node [force, text width=3cm, dashed, left=1cm of substitutes] (state) {Public policies};
\node [force, left=1cm of rivalry] (suppliers) {Bargaining power of suppliers};
\node [force, right=1cm of rivalry] (users) {Bargaining power of users};
\node [force, below of=rivalry] (entrants) {Threat of new entrants};

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Change data from here

% RIVALRY
\node [comment, below=0.25 of rivalry] (comment-rivalry) {(+) A war against Microsoft\\
(+) Limiting sunk costs\\
(+) Coopetition};

% SUPPLIERS
\node [comment, below=0.25cm of suppliers] {(+) Efficiency\\
(+) Attracting other developers\\
(+) Creating a Chrome community};

% SUBSTITUTES
\node [comment, right=0.25 of substitutes] {(+) Portability};

% USERS
\node [comment, below=0.25 of users] {(+) Increasing the user information\\
(+) Reducing the switching costs};

% NEW ENTRANTS
\node [comment, right=0.25 of entrants] {(+) EC vs. Microsoft};

% PUBLIC POLICIES
\node [comment, text width=3cm, below=0.25 of state] {(+) Positively framed\\
(+) Transparency\\
(--) A new monopoly?};

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Draw the links between forces
\path[->,thick] 
(substitutes) edge (rivalry)
(suppliers) edge (rivalry)
(users) edge (rivalry)
(entrants) edge (comment-rivalry);

\end{tikzpicture} 
\caption{FOSS in Chrome influences industry structure by increasing competition}
\label{fig:6forces}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  I'm not seeing how the code you gave us at all relates to the image you want.  I understand not quite being able to get the exact image, but you can at least start by changing the text to get a bit closer.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. TBH, I am completely new to this. I find it quite hard. I come from MS VISIO world :(

Comment: It does take a bit of getting used to.  TeX is more about you describing the content of the document and letting TeX put things where it thinks is best, whereas Word is more about you pushing things around until you think it's best.  But you can look at the tex file you have, and compare it to its output, and pretty easily (IMO) see what parts of the tex file cause what parts of the output.  Then it's just a matter of changing the input to get the output that you want.

Comment: @user6522, if you want to stay with tikz, have a look at the minimla intro at https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf . // However, there are some dedicated packages available like blox (https://mirror.marwan.ma/ctan/graphics/pgf/contrib/blox/blox.pdf) or even closer to waht you'd like as kblocks https://mirror.marwan.ma/ctan/graphics/pgf/contrib/kblocks/kblocks-doc.pdf (see e.g. p.8). // Basically you place boxes, name them, and link them by "wires".

Comment: Your MWE doesn't appear to have anything to do with the image you want to reproduce, except that both are block diagrams.  I would start from scratch and draw the "convert" node, then expand from there.  You will also need `-|` and `|-` to form right angles and locate intersections.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a good point to start with:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning, fit, arrows.meta, calc}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
  basic/.style={
    draw,
    rectangle,
    minimum width=9em,
    text centered
  },
  placeholder/.style={
    basic,
    draw=white
  },
  arrsty/.style={
    draw=black,
    -latex
  }
}

% use sans serif font by default
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={font=\sffamily}]
\node[basic] (tAmount) {tAmount};
\node[basic, below=of tAmount] (tTransferAmount) {tTransferAmount};
\node[basic, right=of tTransferAmount] (tFee) {tFee};

\node[below=of tTransferAmount] (anchor1) {};
% compute the center point of tTransferAmount and tFee
\coordinate (point1) at ($0.5*(tTransferAmount.east)+0.5*(tFee.west)$);
\node[basic, minimum width=7em, text width=7em] (addTotOwned) at (anchor1.center-|point1) {Add to\\tOwned[receipt]};


\node[placeholder, left=of tTransferAmount] (anchor2) {};
% place the other node symmetricly
\coordinate (point2) at ($0.5*(anchor2.east)+0.5*(tTransferAmount.west)$);
\node[basic, minimum width=7em, text width=7em, text centered] (subFromtOwned) at (anchor1.center-|point2) {Subtract from\\tOwned[receipt]};


\node (anchor3) at ($0.5*(addTotOwned.east)+0.5*(subFromtOwned.west)$) {};
\node[basic, below=of anchor3, minimum width=32.8em] (convert) {convert(r$=$rate$\times$t)};

% draw some arrows and put the text in
\path[arrsty] (tAmount)-|(anchor2.center)--(convert.north-|anchor2.center);
\path[arrsty] (tAmount)--node[midway, xshift=1.2em, font=\sffamily\bfseries\small] (ninety-perct) {90\%} (tTransferAmount);
\path[arrsty] (tAmount)-|(tFee);
\path[arrsty] (tFee)--(convert.north-|tFee.center);
\node[xshift=1.2em, font=\sffamily\bfseries\small] at (ninety-perct-|tFee.center) {10\%};
\path[arrsty] (anchor2.center)-| node[pos=0.8, left] {(1)} (subFromtOwned);
\path[arrsty] (tTransferAmount)-| node[pos=0.8, left] {(2)} (addTotOwned);


\node[basic, below=of convert] (rTransferAmount) {rTransferAmount};
\node[basic] (rAmount) at (rTransferAmount-|anchor2.center) (rAmount) {rAmount};
\node[basic] (rFee) at (rTransferAmount-|tFee.center) {rFee};
\node[basic, below=of rAmount, text width=8em] (subFromrOwned) {Subtract from\\rOwned[sender]};
\node[basic, below=of rTransferAmount, text width=8em] (addTorOwned) {Add to\\rOwned[recipent]};
\node[basic, below=of rFee, text width=8em] (subFromrTotal) {Subtract from\\rTotal};

% draw arrows
\path[arrsty] (convert.south-|rAmount)--(rAmount);
\path[arrsty] (convert.south-|rTransferAmount)--(rTransferAmount);
\path[arrsty] (convert.south-|rFee)--(rFee);
\path[arrsty] (rAmount)--(subFromrOwned);
\path[arrsty] (rTransferAmount)--(addTorOwned);
\path[arrsty] (rFee)--(subFromrTotal);

% outer dotted box
\node[fit=(tAmount)(convert)(subFromrOwned)(subFromrTotal), dotted, draw=black, inner sep=1em] (dottedbox1) {};
\node[anchor=north east, xshift=-1em] (TX1) at (dottedbox1.north west) {TX1};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try with the box next door, now!